# Function says node is deleted but is not deleted

Tags: c, pointers, singly-linked-list

So I have this function deleteNode which deletes a node given the firstName of a person in struct PersonalInfo in a singly linked list. It returns 1, meaning it deleted the node, but when I print the linked list it leaves the name in the memory as if nothing happened. If anyone could help me out with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
int deleteNode(PersonalInfo **head, char *firstName){
  if(head!=NULL){
    PersonalInfo *currNode = *head;
    while(currNode!=NULL){
      if(strcmp(currNode->next->firstName, firstName)){ 
        PersonalInfo *nextNode = currNode->next->next;
        free(currNode->next);
        currNode->next = nextNode;
        return 1;
      }   
      if(currNode->next==NULL){
        printf("Operation was unsuccessful: No such name exists\n");
        return 0;
      }   
      currNode = currNode->next;
    }   
  }
  else{
    printf("Head is null, please enter a valid head\n");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the two strings are equal strcmp returns 0. This is the test you should use.

```
if(strcmp(currNode->next->firstName, firstName) == 0)
```

Comment: thanks, as an alternative could I also do !strcmp(arg1, arg2) in this case?

Comment: @chmike not sure if I can piggyback a question like this, but I end up getting a segmentation fault as a cause of using this function. I dont suppose you might be able to see where the cause lies?

Comment: You have to test currNode, not currNode->next. The while condition ensures that currNode is not NULL. But currNode->next might be NULL. So in the if condition, when you try to access currNode->next->firstName, you may dereference a NULL pointer. This causes a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

another possiblity is to replace :

```
if(strcmp(currNode->next->firstName, firstName))
```

with :

```
if(!strcmp(currNode->next->firstName, firstName))
```

Since the return value of str cmp will represent "Flase" only if the strings are the same.

Answer (score 0):

First observation is your strcmp. That block statement will run only for when the strings are unequal. You're not checking for equality. I am assuming you want to run the block statement only when the strings are equal.

The return values are

1. > 0: str1 > str2
2. < 0: str1 < str2
3. = 0: str1 == str2

   if(strcmp(currNode->next->firstName, firstName) == 0)

Comment: The expression will be true if the two strings are different. Which is bigger OR smaller.